# How to create family tree in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-graphview, family-tree

The graphview is perfect but the problem is I want the parent node to be in center and add nodes respectivly to right and left of the parent node.how to do it

I want to create a family tree in flutter using graph view,were the parent node should be in center and ancestors should be added in left and future generation should be added in right.

Comment: What have you tried from the pub?  There are many packages that can present nodes and links using various layout designs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to achieve something like this image.I have tried graphview package

https://cdn.windowsreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/family_tree_software_myheritage_family_tree_builder.jpg